# Почему так говорили: «Он такая дуся»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Почему именно «дуся», откуда взялось это слово?

Мне оно встретилось в современной литературе:

«Брось уточкам хлеб! Они ***такие дуси***».  Тон здесь шутливо-иронический, серьезной и умной девушке вздумалось немного подурачиться.

Слово это редко встретишь (ушло в историю), но потом я вспомнила, что так говорили  раньше гимназистки.

Да и писатели, оказывается,  употребляли его, например: Чебутыкин. Не ходите, ***дуся моя***. [А. П. Чехов. Три сестры (1901)]

Поэтому оно не просторечное, вполне интеллигентные люди могли так сказать.
И вот интересно, связано ли оно с именем Дуся?

Comment: Спасибо, _Sharon_, за интересный вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот какова характеристика этого слова в словаре галлицизмов:
[дуся](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/14480/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8F), -и, *м.* и *ж.* ***douce f.***
**1.** *Дорогая, милая, сладкая; дорогой, милый.* Обращение.
Сделав инженерам глазки, она назвала явившегося проводника миленький и дуся и попросила принести стакан (В. Катаев. Растратчики).
♦ Как дуся. *устар. Как пай-мальчик, послушный, благовоспитанный.* Но тут Курочкин (слышали?) замечает, что все орловцы начинают менять масть — один только Маклер, как дуся, не меняет цвета (И. Ильф. Е. Петров. Двенадцать стульев).
|| *разг., фам.* Ласковое или иронически-ласковое обращение к мужчине или женщине (с оттенком пошловатой фамильярности).
**2.** Дуся. Галлицизированное женское русское имя **Авдотья**.

В девятнадцатом веке и начале двадцатого слово, конечно же, имело первое значение — ласковое обращение (на французский манер).

[Из Нацкорпуса](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8F&kwsz=5&p=15&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal):
— Послушай, моя дуся, сказалъ ей Запорожець такимъ голосомъ, отъ котораго она затрепетала, — я не знаю вашихъ нѣжностей... [П. А. Кулиш. Черная рада (1846-1857)]
Тут, по крайней мере, maman ― дуся, а там, в остальных, Бог весть какая. [Л. А. Чарская. Княжна Джаваха (1903)]
― Что же ты не спишь, дуся?.. Тебе вредно. [И. А. Бунин. Дополнения (1915)]

О таком же значении говорится и в словаре Ефремовой:
[ду́ся](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-22845.htm) м. и ж. *разг.* Употребляется как ласковое обращение к мужчине или женщине, соответствуя по значению словам: *милый, хороший*.

Вполне возможно, что по выходе слова из употребления в тех слоях, которые хоть немного владели французским, оно стало использоваться с оттенком фамильярности.
Я с таким обращением никогда не сталкивалась.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма,  за ответ. Представляете, я еще в школе, читая книги о гимназистках, никак не могла понять, почему они так говорят. И еще тогда связала слово с именем Дуся, так до сих пор и думала. Даже в словарь не догадалась посмотреть. Да, точно, douce [dus] (фр.) милая. В Нацкорпусе иногда встречается «дуся» даже в современных книгах, но сейчас действительно так не говорят. Наверное, как и я, считают, что это просторечие, а это, оказывается, французский язык.

Comment: Кстати, в *пандусе* заложено это французское прилагательное женского рода *douce* в значении *пологий.* Pente douce — пологий скат. Просто во французском pente (скат) женского рода, поэтому и прилагательное ему сопутствует также женского рода.

Comment: А мне кажется, что слово  просто "приспособилось" к  русской речи. Дуся - это, вероятно,  существительное общего рода (женского и мужского).

Answer (score 2):

Мнение о роде существительного (после комментариев)

Словари относят слово "дуся" и к мужскому, и к женскому роду, поэтому считаю, что его действительно можно причислить к существительным общего рода.
Думаю, что его по смыслу и использованию можно сопоставить со словом [душка](http://endic.ru/academic/Dushka-4085.html):
*Он такой душка, прелесть что такое!* (А. Островский)
*— И выйдешь за Гарика, — добавила Вика. — Он такой душка! Душка-лягушка* (Е. Завершнева. Высотка).

Но тогда получается, что правильно нужно писать так: "Он **такой** дуся".

*«Ты бы слышал его Командора! И **он такой дуся**, тебе бы он понравился!» – объясняла она мне...* (А. Фрейдлин. Голубой Майзл)

*...**он такой дуся**, – сказала Филиппова и от избытка чувств даже зажмурилась. – Такой милый, такой красивый. Ариэль... Я обожаю его!* (Т. Тронина. Король колбасных обрезков)